# Jest tests with database reset fail if executed sequentially

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to test my API with jest. Before executing the tests of a test file I want to reset my database using a npm command like this:

```js
import { execSync } from 'child_process'
import prisma from 'lib/prisma'
import { foods } from 'prisma/seed-data'
import { getFoods } from './foods'

beforeAll(() => {
  execSync('npm run db:test:reset')
})

afterEach(async () => {
  await prisma.$disconnect()
})

test('getFoods', async () => {
  const fetchedFoods = await getFoods()
  expect(fetchedFoods).toEqual(foods)
})
```

The `npm run db:test:reset` excecutes this script:

```sh
echo "DROP DATABASE foodplanet WITH (FORCE); CREATE DATABASE foodplanet;" | sudo docker exec -i foodplanet_test psql -U postgres
cat prisma/backups/test/backup.sql | sudo docker exec -i foodplanet_test psql -U postgres foodplanet
```

Everything works fine if I run this test file by itself. However if I execute all tests there are issues with multiple tests executing this script at the same time. Running the tests sequentially with `-i` still results in errors like:

`ERROR:  relation "Account" already exists`

or

`ERROR:  database "foodplanet" does not exist`

I get different errors every time I run my unit test therefore I think there are still multiple instances trying to execute this script at the same time.

What could be the reason that the tests doesn't get executed sequentially?

Comment: Jest can run up to 5 tests concurrently. This is default value for max level of [concurrency](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#maxconcurrency-number).  What are you looking to do? Have a clean slate in the database to have each test run in isolation. Have you considered having each test create its own unique records and clean those records after itself?